# I'm running a PHP script using WAMP, in this case how can I read files from My Documents?

Tags: windows, file-io, wamp

I have a web application that reads files from its local directory (in wamp/www/). This file needed to be accessed by several users so I synced and shared it using Dropbox. Now, is there a shortcut I can use in php commands such as fwrite such that the code is not strictly applicable to only one computer?

For example, I can't code it to fwrite("C:\Users\name\My Documents\") because that is pretty specific to one user and long. I was wondering if there was a shorthand I can use, like %appdata% or %programfiles%?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$_SERVER['HOMEDRIVE'] and $_SERVER['HOMEPATH']
```

For drive and path to user folder respectively

```
print_r($_SERVER)
```

Will display all the environment variables. There you can see which one to select.

Comment: Did you try printing this `print_r($_SERVER)` ?

Answer (score 1):

$fp = fopen("{$_ENV['USERPROFILE']}\My Documents\somefile.txt", 'wb');

See [$_ENV](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) on the manual and also [getenv()](http://php.net/getenv).

Please note this will only work in limited circumstances. You can use this internal function instead:

```
#include<Shlobj.h>

PHP_FUNCTION(win_get_desktop_folder)
{
    char szPath[MAX_PATH];

   if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE)
       RETURN_NULL();

   if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL, szPath,
       CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, FALSE))) {
       RETURN_STRING(szPath, 1);
   } else {
       RETURN_FALSE;
   }
}
```